# Questions are not showing up in pyInquirer library list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd

I was creating a simple command line based quiz game where the user can select an option from the given set of options and move to the next question. I'm using pyInquirer library for this and it's type list for doing the same.

Here's my code:

```
from PyInquirer import style_from_dict, prompt,Token, Separator

style = style_from_dict({
    Token.Separator : '#cc5454',
    Token.QuestionMark : '#673ab7',
    Token.Selected : '#cc5454',
    Token.Pointer : '#673ab7 bold',
    Token.Instruction : '',
    Token.Answer : '#f44336 bold',
    Token.Question : '#673ab7',
})


# this function will take users solution list and correct solutions list and return the score after matching elements of both the lists
def getScore(correct,user):
    score = 0
    for c,u in zip(correct,user):
        if c == u:
            score += 1

    return score

correct_answers = ['Moscow','Yuan']


questions = [
                {
                    'type' : 'list',
                    'name' : 'capital',
                    'message' : '\n what is capital of Russia ?',
                    'choices' : ['Moscow','Serbia','St pittsburgh']
                },
                {
                    'type' : 'list',
                    'name' : 'currency',
                    'message' : '\n what is currency of China ?',
                    'choices' : ['Yuan','Yen','Dollars']
                }
            ]

# passing the above questions dictionary to prompt is responsible for printing questions and options on screen and selecting any one of them.  
answers = prompt(questions,style = style)

# extracting options selected by the user from answers dictionary to match with correct solutions
user_answers = [j for j in answers.values()]

score = getScore(correct_answers,user_answers) 
print('Your score :',score)
```

Everything is working fine except that the questions are not being printed on the screen. Here's a screenshot of the code running in command prompt. The screenshot is of the time when question 1 and related options are being displayed.

[image: a sample screenshot of gameplay]

Can someone tell me where's my error is, how to fix it. And if there's any way replace those question marks from the screen with question numbers

This game has also a UI part which i created using pyfiglet module but i don't think that part has any relation with the above problem

Answer (score 0):

The new line characters in the beginning of your questions seem to be the problem here. Check out the following code as a fix. Also, you can use `rawlist` instead of `list` if you want to add numbers to the choices.

```
questions = [
                {
                    'type' : 'rawlist',
                    'name' : 'capital',
                    'message' : 'What is capital of Russia ?',
                    'choices' : ['Moscow','Serbia','St pittsburgh']
                },
                {
                    'type' : 'rawlist',
                    'name' : 'currency',
                    'message' : 'What is currency of China ?',
                    'choices' : ['Yuan','Yen','Dollars']
                }
            ]
```

Comment: Thankyou very much sir. It works. '\n' in my code wasn't letting the text render on the screen. Again thank you very much